# Display data based on multiple where clause?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, virtuemart

I would appreciate some help with the following.

I have two customfields with ID "6" and "7".

I want to display the customfield_value for customfield(6), only when a specific condition for customfield(7) is met. So it must display the data from customfield(6) only if customfield(7) is a certain value.

Here is the code I have wrote, but it is not working(only gives me blank on loading the data):

```
<?php 

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('customfield_value', 'virtuemart_product_id', 'virtuemart_custom_id')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('jos_virtuemart_product_customfields'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('virtuemart_custom_id'). ' LIKE '. $db->quote('6'). ' AND '. $db->quoteName('customfield_value') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('Frozen') . ' AND '. $db->quoteName('virtuemart_product_id'). 'LIKE ' . $db->quote($product->virtuemart_product_id));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadResult();
echo ($results);

 ?>
```

Here is my edited code showing how the table is working right now I only included 4 customfields, as normally there is about 20:

```
<table style="font-size: 12.5px; width: 100%;" class="orders">
<tr style="border: 1px solid #ffb3b3;">
<th style="text-align:center;border: 1px solid #ffb3b3;">Local ICOS</th>
<th style="text-align:center;border: 1px solid #ffb3b3;">Description</th>
<th style="text-align:center;border: 1px solid #ffb3b3;">Batch ID</th>
<th style="text-align:center;border: 1px solid #ffb3b3;">Temp Zone</th>
</tr>

<?php
// Start the Output
foreach ( $this->products as $product ) {

    // Show the horizontal seperator
    if ($iBrowseCol == 1 && $iBrowseProduct > $BrowseProducts_per_row) { ?>
    <div class="horizontal-separator"></div>
    <?php }
?>

<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ffb3b3; height: 30px; display:;">

<!-- ICOS -->
<td style="width: 80px;text-align: center;">
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('customfield_value', 'virtuemart_product_id')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('jos_virtuemart_product_customfields'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('virtuemart_custom_id') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('5'). ' AND '. $db->quoteName('virtuemart_product_id') . 'LIKE ' . $db->quote($product->virtuemart_product_id));

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadResult();
echo ($results); 
 ?>
</td>

<!-- Description -->
<td style="padding-left: 10px;width: 300px; color: #ff3333;">
<?php  echo $product->product_name; ?>
</td>

<!-- BATCH ID (SKU) -->
<td style="width: 80px;text-align: center;">
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('customfield_value', 'virtuemart_product_id')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('jos_virtuemart_product_customfields'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('virtuemart_custom_id') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('6'). ' AND '. $db->quoteName('virtuemart_product_id') . 'LIKE ' . $db->quote($product->virtuemart_product_id));

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadResult();
echo ($results); 
 ?>
</td>

<!-- Temp Zone -->
<td style="width: 80px;text-align: center;">
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('customfield_value', 'virtuemart_product_id')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('jos_virtuemart_product_customfields'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('virtuemart_custom_id') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('21'). ' AND '. $db->quoteName('virtuemart_product_id') . 'LIKE ' . $db->quote($product->virtuemart_product_id));

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadResult();
echo ($results); 
 ?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Ok. I have a dropdown with "Frozen" as an option. When I select "Frozen", only products with the Temp Zone "Frozen" must be shown. In each  I will need to put a piece of code to show the information depending on the dropdown selection.

Comment: Turn on debug and development errors. There are numerous problems with your code.

Comment: @MailBlade Better than the screenshot that Lodder asked for... the best way to offer db table structures and data is to export a minimal, yet sufficient sample of data from your relevant tables and paste the structures and data into an sqlfiddle link for us.  This way we can develop and test our solutions for you AND future researchers will have absolute clarity about what your issue is and if they are having the same one.

Comment: @MailBlade please improve this open/abandoned question so that we can provide you with optimal support and educate you on better coding practices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mickmackusa. Yeah I know this is not the optimal way to perform this query, but so far it is working as intended. I had another question where I am using some "JOIN" queries

Comment: I want to help you (on all of your questions), but I can't yet.

Comment: Thank you so much! No problem I will try and add a bit more information.

Comment: I'm still eager to offer my assistance.  If you can take the time to create a db-fiddle.com demo containing the necessary tables, we can make some progress.

Comment: I've also solved this issue a while ago, but thank you @mickmackusa. I've just been crazy busy with a new project these past few months and I've still wanted to update my Q's! Apologies will sort it out within the next few days

Answer (score 1):

Try the following which has some modifications to your query and should hopefully print some data for you:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->qn(array('customfield_value', 'virtuemart_product_id', 'virtuemart_custom_id')))
    ->from($db->qn('#__virtuemart_product_customfields'))
    ->where($db->qn('virtuemart_custom_id') . ' = ' . $db->q('6'))
    ->where($db->qn('customfield_value') . ' = ' . $db->q('Frozen'))
    ->where($db->qn('virtuemart_product_id') . '= ' . $db->q($product->virtuemart_product_id));
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

var_dump($results);
```

**Changes:**

- Correct definition for table name
- Replace `LIKE` with `=` as you're not trying to match something similar, but something exact.
- Use `loadObjectList` as you're calling getting data from multiple columns

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I really do appreciate it. I have used this, and now I am getting this as a value: "array(0) { }"

Is that correct?

How do I go about displaying the data for "virtuemart_custom_id[6]" where "virtuemart_custom_id[21]" is "Frozen"?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a row in the database, where `virtuemart_custom_id = 6`, `customfield_value = Frozen` and `virtuemart_product_id = xxx`? 

xxx being whatever `$product->virtuemart_product_id` is equal to

Comment: Yes. You see, "Frozen" value belongs to a different 'virtuemart_custom_id (which is 21)'.

So it must get the value of 'virtuemart_custom_id[6]' IF 'virtuemart_custom_id[21] == "Frozen"'

Comment: @MailBlade - Would you mind taking a screenshot of your database row so that I can see and add it to your question? Still haven't had my morning coffee so I'll need something visual :)

Comment: yes no problem at all. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Here is the first link to show you how it is displayed: https://i.imgur.com/2J3L8f5.png

Here is the second one with the database: 
https://i.imgur.com/tSRhNdg.png

Comment: Just before the database query, please can you add `var_dump($product->virtuemart_product_id);` and let me know what the result is. Also, with the screenshot, I'll need a screenshot of the specific row you're trying to get data from. The one you currently provided shows different rows.

Comment: Ok I have added the above and now am getting this result: string(2) "95" ; and every product has a different number in the brackets and after the brackets.

I'm not really sure how to show that. You see, the output uses this: 
`<?php
// Start the Output
foreach ( $this->products as $product ) {

 // Show the horizontal seperator
 if ($iBrowseCol == 1 && $iBrowseProduct > $BrowseProducts_per_row) { ?>
 <div class="horizontal-separator"></div>
 <?php }
//all <td> elements with php code which extracts the data from the database for each product
?>`

Comment: Is one of the results from the above `string(1) "6"`?

Comment: Not specifically that one, but there is `string(1) "7"` - up till 9

Comment: So that's why the above database query is failing. Because there isn't a row which meets all the requirements of the `where` clauses....specifically `virtuemart_product_id = 6`.

Comment: Ohhh I see now. But shouldn't it still be displaying the values for the other products? Like, if one does have "Frozen" as a value in Temp Zone.

Comment: Nope, it won't display anything unless it meets the conditions of the `where` clauses. I had a look at the requirements for your clause but don't fully understand. Could you update the requirements, using the specific columns names and I can update my answer for you.

Comment: Ok I changed the customfield_id from 6 to 21, which is the temp zone values and it gave me this only for the products where there is "Frozen"

`array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4020 (3) { ["customfield_value"]=> string(6) "Frozen" ["virtuemart_product_id"]=> string(3) "100" ["virtuemart_custom_id"]=> string(2) "21" } }`

Comment: Ok thanks so much for your help. I will do a makeshift table showing what is currently happening.

Comment: I added additional code for you to see. That shows the table structure I use.

Comment: You really need to rewrite this code. Currently, you're running 3 database queries in the foreach loop....meaning if there are 100 products, you're running 300 database queries which is a terrible performance drainer. I suggest you take one step back, have a think about what you want to achieve in this table and then update your question with a detailed description so everything is clear.

Comment: I know it's bad code, but it's all I could get to make it work. It has to be in a table format, and I don't know any other way this could be displayed. Thanks for the help though, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: You should be able to write it as 1 database query outside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but how do I display it for each item if I can't use "foreach"?